# Client side search with filterToolbar does not work first time

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid on which I call filterToolbar and set loadonce=true. When I start searching the search does not work the first time. Second time onward the search works great.
Any idea?
jqGrid('filterToolbar', 
                {stringResult: false,
                 searchOnEnter: false, enableClear: false,
                beforeSearch: function () {
                        presenter.grid.setGridParam({loadonce: "true"});
                }, 
                afterSearch: function () { 
                }});

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the value of `loadonce` should be Boolean instead of String: (`loadonce: true` instead of `loadonce: "true"`).

Seconds, `loadonce` will be used only during processing of the data loaded from the server. If `loadonce: true` is not set, then the HTML table will be filled with the data, but the server respond and the data returned from the server will not be saved locally. On the other side if `loadonce: true` then jqGrid saves the data returned from the server in the local jqGrid option `data`. But I have to repeat that jqGrid fills the `data` only **during processing of the server response**. Additionally jqGrid changes the option `datatype` to `"local"` at the end of processing the data, if `loadonce` is `true`. Thus all will looks later like local filled grid: `datatype` is `"local"` and `data` option is filled with data (all pages of data).

Your current code just set `loadonce` option to `true`. It don't fills `data` option and don't changes `datatype` to `"local"`. Instead of that jqGrid will continue processing of the current filtering request and it will send the request to the server. Only after processing of the server response (the request to return filtered data), jqGrid will take in consideration `loadonce: true` option, it will fill `data` and it will change `datatype` to `"local"`.